# loading jquery in multiple iframes

Tags: jquery, iframe

We have a web application that has a menu bar down the left side and some of the menus are iframes.  Then we have a preview of what the user is building on the right side which is also an iframe.  Those iframes each load their own instance of jquery.  We haven't had any problems with this until we tested it in IE8.  In IE8 we're getting errors "object expected" pointing to the $(document).ready method in the preview window.  I think I've seen this happen before when jquery is loaded multiple times on the same page.

So, I'm thinking that in chrome the scripts are local to each iframe but in IE8 it's more like they're loaded in a global scope.  That's just a guess.  Has anyone run into something like this before?  And, if we need to remove all the duplicate jquery references, is there a way to load it one time and have it shared across all the iframes?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds like a shot in the dark but search for missing semicolons and trailing commas like

```
$("#element").animate({
  width: 300, // comma
}, function() {
  // Completed.
});
```

and

```
$('#element')
.remove()
.end() //missing semicolon

//OtherStuff...
```

Maybe it's not the case, but normaly that makes IE break when other browsers don't.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks.  I did double check my code and found a couple of missing semi colons but after getting everything to run through jslint just fine, I'm still having issues with IE9.  I found an issue where the path to one of the script files has most of the "/" characters stripped out so we're trying to find out how that happened and hopefully that will be the cause.  Thanks.

Comment: You're very welcome, gald I could help. If you need more help, post some code and let me know :)